# RSpec "allow" silently terminates "it" block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an RSpec test like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'outer' do
  describe 'inner' do
    context 'context' do
      it 'my test' do
        puts ":::: BEFORE"
        allow(String).to receive(:broken?).and return(false)
        puts ":::: AFTER"
        expect(0).to eq(1) # Won't be executed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Of course in my own test, I do not use `allow` on a `String`, but on one of my classes, but the effect is the same: When I run this code, *BEFORE* is printed, but *AFTER* is not printed (nor is anything else executed which would come after the `allow`. The effect is, as if the `allow` would terminate the test. There is no error message; RSpec just says "1 example, 0 failures".

Other things worth to mention:

The RSpec mocking is configured with `mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true`, but the effect is the same, independent on whether we specify with `allow` an existing method or (as in my example) a non-existing one.

Warnings are turned on, with `config.warnings = true`.

Any idea why `allow` might show this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a line:

```
allow(String).to receive(:broken?).and return(false)
```

This calls `allow(String).to(receive(:broken?).and(return(false)))`

So you call `return` keyword that silently ends the example.

You should call  [`and_return`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value) not `and return` (note the underscore instead of a space).

Comment: Of course. It's o obvious now! I was just typing it the same way as "to receive", without much thinking.

Comment: @user1934428 that's the problem with those DSLs – easy to read but kind of tricky to write.

Comment: @Only that in this case, it was not really tricky.Just my ability to think logically had gone for a short walk, while I was writing the code.